# How much is the negative affect on performance due to loading and using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do a little bit of third party javascript work for a company where I am able to enter my javascript snippets into the CMS and have it run in the customer facing sites.
I have the option to switch on `JQuery 1.7.1` in the header of the site and I usually choose to do this or not depending on how much more complicated it would make my code if I didn't.

I have often wondered how much difference it would make if I just turned it on in all cases so even simple things like:

```
document.getElementById('myElement');
```

became

```
$('#myElement');
```

Where would the 'breakpoint' be in deciding it was better / more efficient / easier to switch on JQuery?

Today's example that made me think of this was as follows (both regular javascript followed by the JQuery equivalent ):

**Javascript:**

```
if (document.getElementById('myElement')!== null) {
    var oldText = document.getElementById('myElement').innerHTML,
    newText = oldText.replace(/one/i,'two');
    document.getElementById('myElement').innerHTML = newText;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
if ($('#myElement').length !== 0) {
    var oldText = $('#myElement').html(),
    newText = oldText.replace('one','two');
    $('#myElement').html(newText);
}
```

And How much is the negative affect on forcing the clients to download jQuery?

Comment: If jQuery is being included on the home page, you mightaswell include it everywhere else because it will be cached after the home page. (or any other page that is commonly used for that matter.)

Comment: I highly doubt you'll notice the difference

Comment: You can also improve speed by caching `document.getElementById('myElement')` to a variable. However, you'll only notice an improvement when this sequence is run many times.

Comment: Your title asks about **loading** jQuery while the post body asks about **using** jQuery.

Comment: slightly picky @gdoron! I need to **load** Jquery to **use** it. My point was that, knowing the extra amount of 'overhead' (sorry I'm not a web whizz so have probably not used that term correctly either!) that is required to load JQuery, at what point do I benefit from loading it rather than using extra code in vanilla js.

Comment: @DuckinCustard. It's o.k... I was just mentioning it because for the "loading" problem (the time takes the client to download the jQuery file) has other answer, (using of a "global" copy, like the one by Google) Do you want to me do edit the title?

Comment: @gdoron yes, you could do. I looked to do it myself but must be missing something as I can't see how to. I understand that there are other questions on the subject of how long to download JQuery but this was really a combination of that and how much slower it runs things vs how much easier / shorter it makes the code you have to write. If you can summarise that in the title then please go for it :)

Comment: @DuckinCustard. I updated both your question and mine answer. Hope you like it...

Comment: Not that it changes the answers to this question but I do use the Google CDN-hosted copy of JQuery in this case too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference will be minimal, and not worth writing those 10 chars...

> As always, remember that as a developer, your time is typically the most valuable resource. Do not focus on optimization of selector speed unless it is clear that performance needs to be improved.

[**jQuery site**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

And of course `jQuery` has a lot more features than id selectors...

---

A good advise is to cache the queried elements and not query them multiple times, but it's true both with `jQuery` and with vanilla javascript;

From:

```
document.getElementBy('id').value = "foo";
document.getElementBy('id').parentNode.className = "parent";
```

To:

```
var element = document.getElementBy('id')
element.value = "foo";
element.parentNode.className = "parent"
```

or jQuery version:

```
var $element = $('#id');
$element.val("foo");
$element.parent().addClass("parent");
```

Due to jQuery "chainabilty" - cascading styile, you do that with one "chain":

```
$('#id').val("foo").parent().addClass("parent");
```

---

[This `jsperf`](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-jquery-id) shows that `$('#id')` is 3-6 slower than `document.getElementById`
Which means you can have "only" 1,000,000 those operations per second... **"A disaster"**!

**"We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature 
optimization is the root of all evil"**

---

**Regarding to the "loading"- downloading time of the jQuery library.**

- The current minified version of jQuery (1.7.2) size is only 32K, which is almost for sure  smaller than most of images in your website, so it's negligible.
- You can use google global cached copy of jQuery, read more about it in [this long blog post](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/).

> No matter how well optimized your site is, if you’re hosting jQuery locally then your users must download it at least once. Each of your users probably already has dozens of identical copies of jQuery in their browser’s cache, but those copies of jQuery are ignored when they visit your site.
>
> However, when a browser sees references to CDN-hosted copies of jQuery, it understands that all of those references do refer to the exact same file. With all of these CDN references point to exactly the same URLs, the browser can trust that those files truly are identical and won't waste time re-requesting the file if it's already cached. Thus, the browser is able to use a single copy that's cached on-disk, regardless of which site the CDN references appear on.

Comment: And once jQuery is downloaded by the client it's cached anyway.

Comment: @ErikPhilips. That is very true, be he isn't asking about that.

Comment: And if you're loading jQuery from one of the CDNs, if ANY other site the user has visited uses the same CDN and version as you then it will already be there before their first visit to your site. Ex: <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>

Comment: Upvote for "Do not focus on optimization of selector speed unless it is clear that performance needs to be improved."

Comment: +1 jsperf and for then putting that into perspective. Note: you're missing a " at the end of both `.addClass("parent);`s.

Comment: Great advice @gdoron (and everyone else). I guess I _was_ after knowing how much slower I made things by **loading** JQuery but actually the info about how quick **using** it is very interesting too. As for caching elements, this is good advice too and something I am trying to do more after recently watching some good tutorials from Jeff Way on Nettuts+.. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4):

Your plain JS could be a lot more efficient itself without adding jQuery:

```
var obj = document.getElementById('myElement');
if (obj) {
    obj.innerHTML = obj.innerHTML.replace(/one/i,'two');
}
```

Anytime you're repeating the same selector operation multiple times within the same function you should generally cache it into a local variable and you have no need for either of your other temporary variables here.

FYI, if you want a shortcut for `getElementById()`, you can define your own very easily without including a whole library just for that.

```
window.$ = function(id) {
    return(document.getElementById(id));
}
```

There are also much, much smaller libraries than jQuery that gives you basic selector operations.  jQuery itself uses the Sizzle library which is often what I use when I just want selector operations.

I'm not arguing against jQuery if you use/need many of the things that it offers.  It's particularly useful for ajax and many DOM manipulation functions.  But, if your needs are simple, there are often more efficient ways of doing things than including all of jQuery if site efficiency/speed/size is important.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @jfriend00. For some reason when I was writing this before I thought trying to set a var for something that was not found on the page threw an error? Which is why I had my if statement first.. 

Just reworked my live example with your version and it works perfectly well with no error, so not sure what I was doing before! And your obj.innerHTML = obj.innerHTML.replace(/one/i,'two'); example makes perfect sense now I see it!! I still have a lot more to learn I feel!